# Determine if a sequence has "gaps" in R

Tags: r, sequence

I would like to determine if a sequence contains any gaps or irregular steps? Not sure if this is the right way to phrase this and there's a good chance that this is duplicate (but I was unable to find a good question).

The following `has_gap` function gives me the correct results, but seems a bit clunky? Perhaps there is something built-in that I haven't discovered?

```
x1 <- c(1:5, 7:10)
x2 <- 1:10
x3 <- seq(1, 10, by = 2)
x4 <- c(seq(1, 6, by = 2), 6, seq(7, 10, by = 2))

has_gap <- function(vec) length(unique(diff(vec))) != 1

vecs <- list(x1, x2, x3, x4)
sapply(vecs, has_gap)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: You can try: `all(diff(x1) == 1)`

Comment: @Gopala, this would work correctly for `x1` and `x2`, but not `x3`.

Comment: Here is an alternative: `!!diff(range(diff(x)))` and another `var(diff(x)) > 0`

Comment: That second one is brilliant!

Comment: Rudimentary benchmarking (with some larger vectors) gives a slight edge to `!!diff(range(diff(x)))` with `var(diff(x)) > 0` close behind.

Comment: `has_gap4 <- function(x) !isTRUE(all.equal(cor(x, seq_along(x)), 1))` slightly faster for me than the other 3

Comment: which(diff(x) > 1) would print out the locations of all gaps, you could then use has_gap(x) <- function(x) { length(which(diff(x) > 1)) > 0 )

Answer (score 1):

```
library(zoo)
is.regular(x3, strict=TRUE)
is.regular(x3, strict=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by [G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516548/g-grothendieck) in the comments, one approach is:

```r
has_gaps <- \(x)!!diff(range(diff(x)))
```

Another approach might be:

```r
has_gaps2 <- \(x)var(diff(x))>0
```

If performance is an issue, [rawr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2994949/rawr) suggested:

```r
has_gaps3 <- \(x)!isTRUE(all.equal(cor(x,seq_along(x)),1))
```